# My Archetypes-based content type can't be viewed

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, archetypes

I have a little Plone extension which contains a simple Archetypes-based content type (the same which I had not been able to add TTW, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366380/my-archetypes-based-content-type-cant-be-added)); the project setup is [on GitHub](https://github.com/tobiasherp/MyCompany.MyProduct).

After adding an object, I get a `KeyError: 'view'` during execution of the `plone.abovecontenttitle` content provider:

```
{'container': <MyType at /plone/test-for-new-types/a-mytype-object>,
 'context': <MyType at /plone/test-for-new-types/a-mytype-object>,
 'default': <object object at 0x7fc4f8ebe520>,
 'here': <MyType at /plone/test-for-new-types/a-mytype-object>,
 'loop': {},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {'args': ()},
 'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fc4c9484db8>,
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=https://my.testing.site/test-for-new-types/a-mytype-object/mytype_view>,
 'root': <Application at >,
 'template': <FSPageTemplate at /plone/test-for-new-types/a-mytype-object/mytype_view>,
 'traverse_subpath': [],
 'user': <PloneUser 'me'>}
```

It should be reproducible easily with my little extension installed in `develop` mode.

**Edit:**
I noticed that, in the "Installed Product" view (`/portal_quickinstaller/MyCompany.MyProduct/manage_installationInfo`), my product has `Status: installed` and `Types MyType`, but `Content Type Registry entries` is empty (`None`).

Comment: Not reproducable, was getting "AttributeError: @@transform", deriving of your view-template.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for trying. I removed the `transform` part.

Comment: @Ida: I changed the `default_` and `immediate_view` properties to `base_view`; now my type can be viewed that way. I still get the `'view'` KeyError when using the (still existing) `mytype_view`, not understanding the reason. Perhaps it is related to content providers? (I hope this is reproducible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-providers call adapters, which expect a `view`-argument to be present[1] and skin-based templates don't provide, in contradiction to browser-based templates.
To fix that, we can use the global `@@plone`-var[2] like it's done in `main_template`, because `@@plone` is an instance of `BrowserView`, it provides the view-argument:

```
tal:define="view context/@@plone;"
```

Which makes me think, the adapters the content-providers are using, should regard the case that no view is available.

In case you want to have the usual site-structure and just customize the content-part, you could also fill your template into the content-slot, then everything from main_template is inherited, also the view-var:

```
<metal:main metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master">
  <metal:content fill-slot="content">
    Hey, a working content-provider:
    <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontenttitle" />
    Oh, so much more much, here...
  </metal:content>
</metal:main>
```

Which I would recommend, because then you don't need to worry about doing everything right in the header-part. E.g. using "raiseAnon" shouldn't be necessary, because the item's workflow-state is taking care of that and things like the current language will be evaluated, etc.

If you only want to customize the body-part of the content-item, change `content` to `content-core`, the usual content-providers will be rendered then anyways, you don't need to insert them, if you want them in the usual order.

[1]https://docs.plone.org/4/en/old-reference-manuals/portlets/rendered.html

[2]https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/ploneview.py

Comment: Thank you very much! I pushed the minimal possible solution to the GibHub repo.